# Proving an equation is a fuction

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, real-numbers

Prove that the equation

$y^3 + 3xy -5x^3 + 1 = 0$

defines $y$ as a function of $x$ for all $x$ in the real numbers.

Comment: I dont think it is a function because for a single $x$ value it has two y values. for example at $x=1$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I just realised, the y^2 was supposed to be a y^3

Comment: I'll LaTeX the Vieta's method and post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question before edit**:

It doesn't define $y$ as a function of $x$, because it doesn't pass the Vertical Line Test.

Take for example $x=1$, which gives $y^2+3y-4=0 \Leftrightarrow y=1 \vee y=-4$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a depressed cubic equation $y^3+a y + b=0$ in which $a$ and $b$ are functions of $x$. So consider the test (Cardano method) $$4a^3+27b^2=675 x^6-162 x^3+27$$ has no real root and so it is positive.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Originally the question asked was for the equation $y^2 + 3x - 5x^3 + 1 = 0$, and so this is a response to that question.

How you can go about trying to understand this: Note that the given equation is a quadratic equation in $y$, whose coefficients are polynomials in $x$. That is, we can rewrite it as
$$
y^2 + by + c = 0
$$
where $b = 3x$ and $c = -5x^3 + 1$. Thus using the quadratic formula as usual we find that
$$
y = \frac{-3x \pm \sqrt{9x^2 + 20x^3 - 4}}{2}
$$
which is manifestly *not* single-valued. The only way it would be would be if the terms under the square root were zero, which they are not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised it is supposed to be $y^3.

Comment: Does that mean because y is a cubic function it can therefore only have one solution for a given x value?

Comment: Well, no. $y$ may have as many as three solutions; in this case, you can (somehow) show that there is only one. Unfortunately, my method doesn't so easily work in this case, unless you happen to know the Cardano formula off the top of your head...

Answer (score 0):

Let $$y=w-\frac{x}{w}$$

Then you get $$w^3-5x^3+1-\frac{x^3}{w^3}=0 \stackrel{\cdot w^3}{\iff} w^6+(-5x^3+1)w^3-x^3=0 \stackrel{\theta:=w^3}{\iff} \theta^2+(-5x^3+1)\theta-x^3=0 \iff \theta= \frac{5x^3-1\pm\sqrt{25x^6-6x^3+1}}{2} \iff y=\sqrt[3]{\theta}-\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{\theta}}$$

Check your answers, the minus sign case on the quadratic doesn't satisfy the initial equation, thus $y$ is a function.